# Filtering on multiple column in dynamic Telerik RAD grid

Tags: grid, filtering, radgrid

I am preparing dynamic grid using VB.net and RAD grid where columns are getting generated in Run Time. I am trying to apply filter (inbuilt filter) on multiple column at time but application is throwing exception (is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table). This error occurs when I try to apply filter. I am unable to identify root cause. Any input would be appreciated. I am using NeedDataSource() event of Radgrid and this event is throwing above mentioned exception on applying filter.

Thanks in advance.

Rajeev

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the issue is because the column being mentioned in the error cannot access its required DataField. Please check your DataSource configuration closely and see if this DataField's exact name is equals to the one mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Yes you are right but column name is not mentioned in my error message i.e. "is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table" so how do I figure-out that what DataField can not be accessed.

Comment: I am binding columns dynamically. My code is like that:
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gridData" runat="server" OnGridExporting="grid_GridExporting" RenderMode="Auto" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />

Comment: On page_load(): DefineGridStructure(Session("DynamicResultReportGridData"))
 gridData.DataBind()

Comment: Private Sub DefineGridStructure(ByVal allCloumnData As DataSet)
gridData.DataSource = allCloumnData
Session.Add("DynamicResultReportGridData", allCloumnData)
gridData.AllowFilteringByColumn = True
Dim intVal As Integer = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns.Count
For a = 0 To intVal - 1
Dim boundColumn As New GridBoundColumn()
boundColumn.DataField =allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
boundColumn.HeaderText = allCloumnData.Tables(0).Columns(a).Caption().Trim().ToString()
boundColumn.AllowFiltering = True
gridData.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn)
Next

Comment: Protected Sub gridData_NeedDataSource(ByVal Source As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs)
Dim allCloumnData As DataSet =Session("DynamicResultReportGridData")
gridData.DataSource = allCloumnData